# Verificar a existência de dados no banco em PHP

Tags: php

Boa tarde pessoal, estou com uma dificuldade para exibir uma mensagem de "Dados vazios" em meu código, segue como estou fazendo:

```
<?php
$dados = Connection::select("select * from clientes where clientnro ='" . $id_cliente . "'");
$conteudo = $dados->fetchObject();
if ($conteudo->nome != NULL) {
    foreach ($dados as $conteudo) {
        $resultado .= 'Existem clientes - ('$reg['nome']')';
    }else{
        $resultado .= 'Não Existem clientes';
    }
?>
```

Agradeço a ajuda.

Comment: `if(!empty($conteudo)){` nem sempre `$counteudo->dados` vai existir logo a propriedade vai gerar warning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$conteudos = $dados->fetchObject();
$resultado = '';
if (count($conteudos) > 0) {

      foreach ($conteudos as $user) {

           $resultado .= 'Existem clientes - (' .$user['nome']. ')';

      }

}   

else{

  $resultado = 'Não Existem clientes';
}
```

No entanto a variável (`$id_cliente`) que entra na query de SQL indica que está a ir buscar o id do cliente, se tiver a certeza que é um id unique na sua tabela recomendo:

```
$conteudos = $dados->fetchObject();
if (count($conteudos) > 0) {
      $resultado = 'Existem clientes - (' .$conteudos[0]->nome. ')';
}   

else{

  $resultado = 'Não Existem clientes';
}
```